# How can I refer a string by an int in Java?

Tags: java, android

this is my configuration file

```
//COLORS
public final String COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND = "#8A2BE2";
public final String COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR = "Color.WHITE";
```

and this is my code

```
tv.setTextColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND);
```

but it doesnt work, because setTextColor takes an int

so how can I refer that color #8A2BE2 with an int, so I can use it in setTextColor()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND));
```

Comment: @J.Kowalski Thanks! Although please note this will not work for `COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR`, unless that is defined as `"#FFFFFF"` (equivalent to white). If you want to use the `Color.WHITE` constant do it like Fildor suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static final int COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

The Color-Constants are already of type int.

Comment: I want to be able to be more specific than that using colors of the type #8A2BE2

Comment: @J.Kowalski You can still use an int for the constant and parse the Hex-Color-Value to int.

Comment: By the way: I +1-d Sebastians answer for suggesting using the resources architecture of Android. I consider that most flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Store colors in colors.xml like this:

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<resources>
<color name=”toast_background”>#8A2BE2</color>
<color name=”toast_text_color”>#8A2BE2</color>
</resources>
```

Then :

```
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toast_background);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the [parseColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29) method available in the android.graphics.Color package.

Answer (score 1):

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8A2BE2"));
```